# How to append all list or union all set in a map's image in Isabelle

Tags: concatenation, fold, isabelle, set-union

Assume that p is a map defined as `nat ⇒ string list` or  `nat ⇀ string list` and I want to append all string list in p's image

As the similar question, if p is a map defined as `nat ⇒ string set` or  `nat ⇀ string set` and I want to union all string list in p's image.

For example, for `p: 0 -> ["0.0"]; 1 -> ["1.0","1,1"]`, I want to get the result as `["0.0", "1.0", "1.1"]`

for `p: 0 -> {"0.0"}; 1 -> {"1.0","1,1"}`, I want to get the result as `{"0.0", "1.0", "1.1"}`

It seems that in Isabelle has `⋃` to deal with the set union, but I can't find anything about append a set of lists.

Comment: I have no idea what you want. For `p: 0 -> ["0.0"]; 1 -> ["1.0","1,1"]`. What do you want to have? "0.01.01.1"?

Comment: Maybe that: definition h :: "(nat ⇒ string set) ⇒ string set" where  "h p = ⋃ (p ` UNIV)"

Comment: I mean if `p: 0 -> ["0.0"]; 1 -> ["1.0","1,1"]`, I want to get the result as `["0.0", "1.0", "1.1"]`

Comment: I have provided the set version. For lists, this is not possible, because lists are always finite (take `p: _ -> ["0"]`).

Comment: If you really really need lists and you know things are finite, something like `fold (@) (map (the o p) (sorted_list_of_set (dom p))) []` might work, but (i) it will be annoying to work with, (ii) it is not executable, and (iii)  it will be very very annoying to work with (sledgehammer won't like, auto won't like it, and so on). I strongly advise against, unless really required.